# laravel 5.6 Eloquent One to Many Relationship on multiple tables

Tags: php, database, model, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I have some specific database structure as the below diagram

[image: Database Structure]

So basically one **Part** can have multiple specifications but those specifications are not exist in a known table. Specifications can be in any of the **rsnf_part_specification** , **rgr_part_specification** or **dcd_part_specification** tables. I need for find a way to know which table through the **part_owner_short_code** FK because its the specifications tables prefix **rsnf,dcd or rgr**.

Is it possible to do this using Laravel 5.6 Eloquent Relationship ?

Comment: There are 22 part owners I just mentioned 3 of them, which means there will be 22 "OWNERPREFIX_part_specifications" tables. I will

Answer (score 2):

You have to modify your table structure like this

```
owners(id, code, status)
parts(id, owner_id, category_id, name) //should add owner_id as FK 
part_specifications(id, part_id, name, description) //no need to prefix owner code
```

**Owner Model**

```
class Owner extend Model {
    protected $table = 'owners';

    public function parts(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Part', 'owner_id');
    }

    public function partSpecification(){
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\PartSpecification', 'App\Part', 'owner_id', 'part_id');
    }

}
```

**Part Model**

```
class Part extend Model {
    protected $table = 'parts';

    public function owner(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Owner', 'owner_id');
    }

    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'category_id'); // Define Category model
    }
}
```

**Part Specification Model**

```
class PartSpecification extend Model {
    protected $table = 'part_specifications';

    public function part(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Part', 'part_id');
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to use the existing specification structure then try this

**Owner Model**

```
class Owner extend Model {
    protected $table = 'owners';

    public function parts(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Part', 'owner_id');
    }
}
```

**Part Model**

```
    class Part extend Model {
        protected $table = 'parts';

        public function owner(){
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Owner', 'owner_id');
        }

        public function category(){
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'category_id'); // Define Category model
        }

        public function rnsPartSpecification(){
            return $this->hasMany('App\RnsPartSpecification','part_id'); //define RnsPartSpecification model 
        }

        public function rgrPartSpecification(){
            return $this->hasMany('App\RgrPartSpecification','part_id'); //define RgrPartSpecification model 
        }

        public function dcdPartSpecification(){
            return $this->hasMany('App\DcdPartSpecification','part_id'); //define DcdPartSpecification model 
        }
    }
```

**Fetch Data**

```
$parts = Part::with('owner', 'RsnfPartSpecification', 'RgrPartSpecification', 'DcdPartSpecification')->get();

foreach($parts as $part){
    if($part->owner->code == 'rsnf'){
        print_r($part->rnsPartSpecification)
    }else if($part->owner->code == 'rgr'){
        print_r($part->rgrPartSpecification)
    }else{
        print_r($part->dcdPartSpecification)
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. The thing is that I have to distribute part specifications on multiple tables. Becuz the data is HUGE each specifications table has aroound 150,000 Records  that is way i separated the tables and prefixed them ):

Comment: i have updated answer with your existing specification structure, try it

Comment: I appreciate that @rkj and its one of the options as I have but it might be expensive query as well. Keep in mind that there are 22 part owner I just mentioned 3 of them which means 22 "_part_specifications" tables. I will update my question with this info